# How to disable write cache for all external drives on Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I want to disable it on external drives to ensure that the data is really copied/written to the drive, write cache makes it difficult for me to decide whether the data is already copied/written or not.

I tried to issue:

```
hdparm -W 0 /dev/sdb
```

but it said:

```
/dev/sdb:
 setting drive write-caching to 0 (off)
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 write-caching =  1 (on)
```

So, anyway, it failed to disable the cache.

Comment: wouldn't that fit more to [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: You might want the `sync` option to `mount` and also use the `sync` command.